# Is it possible to dynamically change the URL of a webpage?

Tags: php, javascript, url, dynamic

I just wanted to know, is there any possible way to change the URL that appears in the address bar of a webpage dynamically? Like, maybe there are two buttons on the webpage, and when the user clicks one it will (or won't it does not matter) refresh the page and the url will be mysite.com/page1, or if the user clickes the second button, the url that appears in the address bar will be mysite.com/page2?

I do not need it to chaneg the domain, just the part after.

Just wanted to say, that I DO NOT want to go to another page. This must be done on one page. It does not matter if it is done with JS, PHP, or via the .htaccess file, but it must do this with only one page.

Answer (score 4):

Outside of changing the `.location` you only really have control over the `window.location.hash`.

```
window.location.hash = "boo"; http://mysite.com -> http://mysite.com/#boo
```

This is the *only* way to **not** go to a new page while changing the URL. All other methods will refresh the page or redirect the page:

1. `window.location` redirects user when changed
2. `window.location.pathname` redirects user when changed
3. `window.location.search` redirects user when changed
4. `window.location.hash` **does not** redirect user when changed

You can also just change the non domain path by using a relative url:

```
window.location = "page1"; // include forward-slash if necessary
                           // goes to http://somesite.com/page1
```

Comment: Jonathan you are one stackoverflowin sonofagun!

Comment: I appreciate your kindness, jeerose. Thank you for contributing as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely (and easily) serve the same page off both `/page1` and `/page2` and have the buttons navigate respectively to one and the other -- "refreshing the page", as you say (i.e. loading it up again from the server, or browser cache), and of course change accordingly what appears in the address bar, too.  However, I don't see what's the *point* of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you want.

Is it that in both cases, you want the same page to be shown but with different urls ?

In that case, you could write a .htaccess file to redirect to the same page for both /link1 and /link2 and point the button to either of the links.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this question in case others come along.

This can now be handled via javascript using [`pushState()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-history-pushstate). There's a couple of libraries (such as [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js)) that aim to ease implementation across different browsers currently without proper support. However, if you'd like see a simple usage example without the use of such libraries, feel free to check out the following article on Hawkee

[Dynamically change URLs using Push and Popstate](http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9940/)